# How to calculate time in mysql query Php

Tags: php, mysql

I have following table in database name "booking"

```
id userId taxiId serviceStarted duration(in minutes)
1   3   2   2019-10-30 13:06:59 20
```

Now i want to know estimatedTime ( when service will end) so can i do this using mysql query ?
i want something like this in mysql query

```
serviceStarted + duration - currentdatetime
```

in mysql query,Is this possible ? if yes then how can do this ?

Comment: How this `serviceStarted + duration - currentdatetime`  will give you estimated time ?

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm: i am not sure but i want something like 

serviceStarted + 20 (minutes) 

2019-10-30 13:26:59

now calculate with current datetime, i want difference between serviceStarted + 20 (minutes) - currentTime so that i know how much time left for complete service, Thats it, hopefully you understand my point

Comment: See about date and time functions

Answer (score 1):

This query returns how much time left for complete the service, in hours:minutes:seconds: `(serviceStarted + duration) - currentdatetime`

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), ADDTIME(serviceStarted, SEC_TO_TIME(duration*60))))
```

To get the minutes left:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), ADDTIME(serviceStarted, SEC_TO_TIME(duration*60)))/60
```

For example, if serviceStarted = '2019-10-30 16:35:00' and NOW() = '2019-10-30 12:12:49', the result will be:

```
282.1833
```

therefore 282.183/60 = the service will be completed after 4,703055 hours from now.

---

[`ADDTIME`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_addtime.asp) add the seconds (2nd argument) to the datetime (1st argument).

[`SEC_TO_TIME'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) convert from seconds to time.

[TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) examples:

> ```
> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01');
>         -> 3
> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2002-05-01','2001-01-01');
>         -> -1
> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55');
>         -> 128885
> ```

Note that if the service is already completed, the query returns a negative amount.

Comment: not working,showing following result

FUNCTION TIMEADD does not exist

Comment: @deepikaaggarwal sorry, mistype, it's ADDTIME, see my edit.

Comment: @user232342558: still not working, showing following error

" Unknown column 'serviceStarted' in 'field list' "

Comment: @deepikaaggarwal it depends on your table structure. You posted the column `serviceStarted` in your question. Maybe you typed it wrong? You must use the real column name

Comment: Where is "from" in your query ?

Comment: @deepikaaggarwal added the FROM. You must add the WHERE clauses, if there are.

Comment: result is in minutes or seconds ?

Comment: @deepikaaggarwal in seconds

Comment: in database column name "serviceStarted=2019-10-30 15:20:00" and run your query and its giving me value " -19625"  , what it means ?

Comment: @deepikaaggarwal what's the value for `duration`?

Comment: duration value is " 20 "

Comment: @deepikaaggarwal yes, its the time in hours, minutes and second left for the service completion. It's also a readable format, which format do you need?

Comment: but this is showing wrong result because duration is minutes, i have around 3 minutes left for complete service but as you saying its showing in hours,minutes and seconds ( 05:41:33 ), i just want "minutes" left as result , can you return result only in " Minutes" , only minutes ( which is left ) ?????

Comment: i changed servicestarted time as " 2019-10-30 16:35:00 " and duration is 20 but showing wrong result

Comment: i think your query is right but problem is with timezone, i want to use asia/kolkata time zone ( IST)

Comment: @deepikaaggarwal then the result depends on which time zone is using the MySQL server. Instead of NOW() write CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'SYSTEM','Asia/Kolkata') (search in the Web if Asia/Kolkata is a correct parameter to pass in it). If my answer solved your problem, please flag it as accepted (with the ✔ under the vote)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Set @tsesttime  = '2019-10-30 13:06:59';
SET @duration = 20;
SELECT TIMEDIFF(@tsesttime + INTERVAL  @duration MINUTE,NOW()) ;
```

The Result is(of course at runtime=

```
03:45:27
```

your SELeCT could be then

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(serviceStarted + + INTERVAL `duration(in minutes)` MINUTE,NOW()) ;
```

Comment: where is "where condition in query" ? i am new in php and mysql so i am not understand yout point, and please write single code/single query so i can check and implement in myside

Comment: You asked for a date calculation nad showed how you can Do it in your mysqöl query. I don't know the rest of your query so i can't write it in my answer.  The where clause has nothing to do with php, php only shows the result of teh query. Also you didn't postany php code either.