# Mysql Now () is not workig phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I am working on mysql with PHP,I am trying to calculate and fetch estimated time

My following query (static) is working but whenever i try to use dynamic (Use now() in mysql) then not working,

working query is

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2019-10-30 16:10:00',ADDTIME(serviceStarted, SEC_TO_TIME(duration*60))) as estimatedTime FROM usr_booking WHERE bookingId='5';
```

i just repaced current datetime to NOW(),but following query is not working

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),ADDTIME(serviceStarted, SEC_TO_TIME(duration*60))) as estimatedTime FROM usr_booking WHERE bookingId='5';
```

Why NOW() not working in mysql ?

Comment: What's the output of your query and what did you expect to get? Does it give any error or warning?

Comment: @cynical: its showing different result/wrong result

Comment: @Cynical: static query showing correct result ( time left/estimated time) but with use of now() showing wrong result "343"

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide those different/wrong results, and the correct values you expect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58621096/how-to-calculate-time-in-mysql-query-php This question is being posted by you and the query that you have an issue with, is working in this post?

Comment: for example in database i changed "serviceStarted" as "2019-10-30 16:35:00" and now current time is "2019-10-30 16:45:00" and duration is "20" in database so result should show as "10" (minutes left)

Comment: @Cynical: i think problem is with time zone , thats why static and dynamic query result are different, how can i get result according to IST ( timezone = asia/kolkata) ?